# ROS Indigo - rviz maker turned white after update

Tags: ros, rviz, update, markers, markers.rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After latest update of ros-indigo-moveit and rviz, the markers (which had red and blue colors before) turned white.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265425/ros-indigo---rviz-maker-turned-white-after-update/) by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-04**:
"Markers turned white" points to problems with your TF tree. Have you changed anything there? Can you double check that RViz still has the correct *Fixed Frame* configured?

**Comment by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on 2017-07-04**:
Thanks a lot for your comment. I'm sure nothing has changed in the TF tree and I double checked that the correct *Fixed Frame* is configured. Immediately before the update everything was working fine but soon after without me changing anything at all the two visualization markers turned white.

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2017-07-06**:
I get the same problem. The visualization_marker message has the correct color values but all markers appear white.

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2017-07-06**:
I opened a new issue on RViz Github. Let's see what they say. Maybe this is intended behaviour.
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1120

**Comment by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on 2017-07-08**:
Thanks a lot gaya. I guess we are having the exact same problem. Let's hope someone answers in Rviz Github.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-07-12**:
If either of you have a reproducible example, I'd appreciate it if you could share it on the issue https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1120. That will help me debug the problem.

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-07-31**:
I have the same problem. Did any of you find a solution? It would be extremely helpful for my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been solved by @William in the following pull request: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1132.
It should take effect with the next sync, I guess anytime within the next couple of weeks.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1